# Writing matlab vector to a file that is matlab readable

Tags: matlab

For matlab: Is there a way to write the value of a vector to a file that can later be opened and read by another matlab program?

Specifically: I have a matlab program that computes a binary-valued vector $zvector$ with 10^7 entries.  I want to write $zvector$ as data to an output file so that it can be emailed and easily read as input to another matlab program. Ideally, the output file would be called “Output.m” and would look like:

zvector=[
0
1
1
…
0
1
];

I like the .m format because it is easy to use for matlab input.  I have experimented with matlab’s write() and fwrite() commands, with no success.  I observe that these generate files that cannot be easily read as matlab-recognizable inputs (at least, I do not know how to read from them). Is there a way to accomplish my goals?  Thanks.

---

PS:  I am interested in the easiest way.  If this involves a different type of file format (not a .m format) that is fine.  However, in that case, can you provide both the writing and reading commands? Thanks again.

Comment: You could save it as a MAT file.

Comment: Thanks.  I just did "help mat" and "help .mat" and "help MAT" to no avail.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Comment: Thanks!  Actually in between comments I found another helpful page on the mat format, and I wrote a test program for writing and reading.  It works! Thanks again.  The page I used was: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Awesome! Don't think I helped much, so can you write an answer about what you did instead?

Comment: We think alike.  Already did.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @edwinksl for pointing me in the right direction with MAT files.  I do not know the accepted practice here, but in stackexchange math it is encouraged to answer your own question if a hint from comments got you all the way there.  So I will answer my own question.

---

The Mat format does this well.  Here are example script files for reading and writing in the Mat format (see also links in above comments for more documentation):

***Script file OutputTest.m:

```
filename = 'TestFile.mat';

TestVector=[1 1 0 1];

save(filename, 'TestVector');
```

***Script file IntputTest.m

```
filename = 'TestFile.mat';

file=load(filename);

z =file.TestVector;

z
```

---